# ¿Existe una manera simple de convertir una lista de tipo str a una de tipo int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, integer

Esto es lo que intente:

ejemplo1:

```
a=['1','2','3','4']

for m in range(len(a)):
int(a[m])

print(a)
```

Pero luego me di cuenta de que por ejemplo en:

ejemplo 2:

```
a=['1','2','3','4']

b= []


int(a[0])

b = b + [a[0]]


print(b)

#Output b = ['1']
```

Lo que quiere decir que int(a[0]) no hace nada por lo que pude comprobar .Me podrian dar consejos de que podria hacer? estoy un poco perdido aqui.

Comment: `b = [int(n) for n in a]` sin necesidad de imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tú estás bajo la impresión de que hacer esto:

```
int(a[0])
```

antes que esto:

```
b = b + [a[0]]
```

Tiene el efecto de cambiar el primer elemento del arreglo `a` de string a int.

Esto no es así, en efecto, `int(a[0])` te retorna un `1`, que es el resultado de transformar a entero el componente `0` del arreglo `a`. Pero esta operación no cambia el elemento del arreglo en el arreglo mismo, sino que te regresa una copia de `a[0]` ya transformada a tipo entero.

Para lograr lo que quieres debes hacer esto:

```
b = b + [int(a[0])]
```

De esta manera, creas una lista que contiene al número `1` por medio de la expresión `[int(a[0])]` y después unes los elementos de la lista `b` y la lista `[int(a[0])]` con la expresión `b = b + [int(a[0])]`.

Comment: Si! muchas gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, para tener una copia del arreglo a ya transformada a puros enteros, haz lo que dijo @Bryro.

Answer (score 3):

Una manera sencilla que he encontrado para transformar la misma lista:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
```

lo que te devuelve:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

con la funcion int() combierte string a int

```
a=['1','2','3','4']

b= [int(x) for x in a]

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función **map**.

Ejemplo:

```
numeros_str = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Función para convertir una cadena de texto en un entero:

```
def str_a_int(cadena):
    return int(cadena)
```

Usar `map()` para aplicar la función `str_a_int()` a cada elemento de la lista *numeros_str*:

```
numeros_int = list(map(str_a_int, numeros_str))
```

Answer (score -1):

También se podría hacer de esta manera:

```
lista = ["1", "2", "3.54", "4.7"]

for i in range(0, len(lista)):
    if float(lista[i]) % 1 == 0:
        lista[i] = int(lista[i])
    else:
        lista[i] = float(lista[i])

print(lista)
```

Hola, después de tanto tiempo descubrí otras 2 maneras:

```
lista = ["1", "2", "3", "4.45", "5"]

lista = list(map(lambda x: round(float(x), 3), lista))
print(lista)
```

Esto es si tienes un decimal en la lista pero si tienes solamente números enteros como strings se puede de esta manera también:

```
lista = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

lista = list(map(lambda x: int(x), lista))
print(lista)
```

Comment: El OP pide expresamente convertir a `int`. Para chequear si es un `float` bastaría con preguntar `if "." in lista[i]:`. Si es `float`, conviertes dos veces el mismo elemento (se puede lograr lo mismo con un solo `float`).

Comment: No, fijate que los elementos de la lista son string y yo lo que estoy haciendo es que en el condicional if, paso los valores tempralmente a float pero no se almacenan en una variable. Por lo que si el flotante temporal si tiene un decimal mayor que 0, ahí sí se almacena en una variable.

Comment: Estas evaluando dos veces el `float`. Si lo guardas o no es irrelevante. Además, el problema sólo indica enteros.